# Call to operating system to open url?

Tags: python, linux, url, operating-system

What can I use to call the OS to open a URL in whatever browser the user has as default? 
Not worried about cross-OS compatibility; if it works in linux thats enough for me!

Comment: What os are you looking for since Windows, MacOS and Linux all have a different calling convention.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Here is how to open the user's default browser with a given url:

```
import webbrowser

url = "https://www.google.com/"

webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

Here is the documentation about this functionality. It's part of Python's stdlibs:

http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html

I have tested this successfully on Linux, Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: On OS X 10.8.2 with Python 2.7.2 this does *not* appear to work.  However, it works fine on Windows 7 with Python 2.7.3.  Also works fine on Ubuntu 12.04 with XFCE 4.8 and Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Okay, on OS X 10.8.2 with Python 2.7.4 this does appear to work.  So, annoyingly it probably only reliably works on newer versions of Python.

Comment: I get

          webbrowser.open(url[, new=0[, autoraise=True]])
                        ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.8.4 with Python 2.7.2 and verified it does indeed work. However, if you use the url 'google.com' it fails without error. You need to specify 'http://google.com'.

Comment: FWIW, this is what `import antigravity` uses: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/antigravity.py

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64bit with Python 2.7.10 and it always opened a browser. But sometimes that browser was Internet Explorer instead of the default (Firefox) browser.

Answer (score 45):

Personally I really *wouldn't* use the `webbrowser` module.

It's a complicated mess of sniffing for particular browsers, which will won't find the user's default browser if they have more than one installed, and won't find a browser if it doesn't know the name of it (eg Chrome).

Better on Windows is simply to use the `os.startfile` function, which also works on a URL. On OS X, you can use the `open` system command. On Linux there's `xdg-open`, a freedesktop.org standard command supported by GNOME, KDE and XFCE.

```
if sys.platform=='win32':
    os.startfile(url)
elif sys.platform=='darwin':
    subprocess.Popen(['open', url])
else:
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', url])
    except OSError:
        print 'Please open a browser on: '+url
```

This will give a better user experience on mainstream platforms. You could fall back to `webbrowser` on other platforms, perhaps. Though most likely if you're on an obscure/unusual/embedded OS where none of the above work, chances are `webbrowser` will fail too.

Comment: I've just looked at the source for webbrowser, and I'm not sure I agree with you. Only the unix sniffing looks a bit unreliable, and even it should work correctly in KDE or GNOME (it probably could use a patch to use `xdg-open`, though `xdg-open` uses similar sniffing anyway). The win32 implementation, for instance, uses `os.startfile()` already, and it also has a fallback.

Comment: The webbrowser module worked for me when I had Safari as my default browser, and also when I had Chrome as my default browser on Mac.

Comment: Note that webbrowser uses `xdg-open` now, too. Thus this answer is outdated on modern python and there is no reason not to use the webbrowser module.

Comment: `xdg-open` throws an error for `data:` URLs. Simply running `webbrowser.open("data:text/plain,Hello,%20World!")` opens the correct browser (Firefox) on my system (Debian 11), though the user needs to refresh the page before it loads due to https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module.

```
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 7):

Then how about mixing codes of @kobrien and @bobince up:

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser
import sys

url = 'http://test.com'
if sys.platform == 'darwin':    # in case of OS X
    subprocess.Popen(['open', url])
else:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [webbrowser module](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html).