# How to visit a link which is in inbox of Gmail?

Tags: python

I have written code to login to the mail. How to get a response from the given link (https://nationalskillsregistry.com) in Gmail inbox?

```
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import datetime

detach_dir = '.' # directory where to save attachments (default: current)
user = "something@gmail.com"
pwd = "password"
subject_filter='(SUBJECT "Daily News ")'

# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
print "logged in successfully..."
m.select()
typ, data = m.search(None, subject_filter)
for num in data[0].split():
    rv, data = m.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    if rv != 'OK':
      print "ERROR getting message", num
      #return

msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
print msg.get_payload(decode=True)
m.close()
m.logout()
```

This is the mail which I have:

> Subject : Daily News - Announcing
>
> Body :
>
> Kindly note, if you are making online payment you do not need to visit
> any POS centre. Your account will be immediately renewed.  If your
> account is not renewed immediately then wait for 24 hours and check if
> the validity has been extended.  Kindly do not make multiple online
> payments. Visit us at https://nationalskillsregistry.com.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 steps you'll want to do -- extract the URL from the email, and then open it in a browser.

Step 1 will be the hard part. I'd recommend using Regular expressions to try and parse the email to pull out the URL. There are a lot of resources online that can help you with this. One of my favorites for testing regexs is [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).
The code should be pretty straightforward.

```
import re
 ...
expr = r'((http)s?:\/\/((\.)?\w+)+(\/\S*)*)'
#Parse with regex: Grabs possible URL (first only). Case insensitive.
matches = re.match( expr, msg, re.I)
url = matches[0]
```

[Step 2 is easy enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216985/call-to-operating-system-to-open-url) --

```
import webbrowser

...

webbrowser.open(url)
```

Or, if you want to download the raw HTML:

```
import urllib2

...

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

If you [need to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python), you can use urllib to do the lifting.

```
import urllib

...

urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

---

As for that regex, let's break it out a bit:

```
(  (http)s?:\/\/((\.)?\w+)+(\/\S*)*  )
```

First off, note that it's all in parentheses. Parentheses mean that it's a capture group, so we'll be able to get to it later.

```
(http)s?
```

This will look for the string 'http', which may or may not have an 's' following it.

```
:\/\/
```

This will look for '://' -- the '\' are there because the '/' need to be escaped.

```
(\.)?\w+)+    #Grab everything between :// and /
```

This bit's fun. It'll look for a period (that is optional), followed by ''word characters'' -- letters or numbers, not punctuation or whitespace.
It will repeat this 1 or more times. In doing so, it'll grab strings like
    amazon.com
    amazon.co.uk

```
(\/\S*)*
```

This will grab any number of strings that begin with a '/', and may have words following them. This is things like
    /
    /home/
    /foo.html?q=bar

Comment: Basically, I don't need to open it in a browser. I need to get a response from the link and there will be a file which has to be downloaded on clicking a button.

Comment: Updated my answer