# Open first video by searching in youtube, using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, youtube

I try this and don't know how to open the first video. This code opens the search in the browser.

```
import webbrowser

def findYT(search):
    words = search.split()

    link = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

    for i in words:
        link += i + "+"

    time.sleep(1)
    webbrowser.open_new(link[:-1])
```

This successfully searches the video, but how do I open the first result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to operating system to open url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216985/call-to-operating-system-to-open-url)

Comment: no thanks, I think, I must find the first video's link in HTML document,  by parsing it.. but I want easy way)

Comment: you cant search with that code (i guess)?

Comment: this just opens the search thats all

Comment: you will have to parse for this. want a code for that?

Comment: no, it searching, this code is working, I need to continue and add the part to open the first result link, I need any function or library

Comment: yeah i want code to parse

Comment: your code literally opens the search in the browser. you cant get the first link unless you parse it

Comment: yes, i need to parse it and get that link, but how?

Comment: You should not be asking someone to do something for you. Rather give your attempts to solve it and request when you are unable to succeed in your attempts. Please share your attempts on `parsing` the outcomes.

Comment: let him, i could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common approach would be to use two very popular libraries: `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. `requests` to get the page, and `BeautifulSoup` to parse it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import webbrowser

def findYT(search):
    words = search.split()

    search_link = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + '+'.join(words)
    search_result = requests.get(search_link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(search_result, 'html.parser')
    videos = soup.select(".yt-uix-tile-link")
    if not videos:
        raise KeyError("No video found")
    link = "https://www.youtube.com" + videos[0]["href"]

    webbrowser.open_new(link)
```

Note that it is recommended not to use uppercases in python while naming variables.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have to webscrape. Python can´t see what is on your screen. You have to webscrape the youtube page you are searching and then you can open the first `<a>` that comes up for example. ('' is a url tag in html)

Things you need for that:

- BeautifulSoup or selenium for example
- requests

That should be all that you need to do what you want.