# Can't open link from jupyter project

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am new at using jupyter notebook. I build a dashboard using jupyter and dash, then it give me link to open my project

```
  Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
```

But I can't open that link and the browser said "This site cannot be reached 127.0.0.1 refusing to connect". I already change the 127.0.0.1 to my ip address, but still get the same error. When I open just my ip address it redirect me to localhost xampp. But, when I adding port after it, it gets the same error again.
What configuration I can do to open that link ?

Thank You :)

Comment: Does below solution work for you ?

Comment: none of these work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216985/call-to-operating-system-to-open-url. Thiscould be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, which opens up a website and worked for me when I ran it:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection, socket
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: still can't open it

Comment: the message still same like before

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Can you try running as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I am connect to the Internet.

Comment: Can you try opening up google itself? Does it work for google?

Comment: Then that might be a personal problem related to your specific PC or link; the server or host might refuse to connect because of authorization issues or the like.