# Python, how to bring up page with Google Search results?

Tags: python

On Python, is there a way you can to bring up a page showing results for a query? I don't want to get a list containing the URLs from google search; I want the program to open up a new tab showing the results from a google search. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want the script to run a google search in a new browser tab? If so does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216985/call-to-operating-system-to-open-url) help? Or are you trying to generate a whole new page as opposed to just opening a URL? If so do you have any experience at all with creating websites or webpages via Python?

Comment: If my answer helped you get the solution, you can accept it by clicking the gray checkmark next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using selenium:

```python
from selenium import webdriver

query = input("What Would You Like To Search: ")
words = query.replace(" ", "+")

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q={words}&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8")
```

Comment: No offense, but would *not* recommend using this. You have to install selenium using ``pip``.

Comment: Fair enough. Just thought I'd point it out in case someone has selenium already.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. The standard library has the [`webbrowser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html).

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=xkcd%20python")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open up a new tab in a browser, you can use `webbrowser`:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

where `url` is the URL you're aiming for. The documentation says:

> Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the default browser, if possible, otherwise equivalent to open_new().