# How to use the same chromedriver browser for two Python scripts

Tags: python

it is possible to use two python scripts on the same chromedriver browser if the first python script opens the page with chromedriver and the second one python script search on google on the page opened by the chromedriver in the first python script.

I wrote the following code but I don't know how to do what I said above.

First Python Script:

```
import time
import second_script.py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver87/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
execfile('second_script.py')
```

And the second one should contain:

```
import time
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton").click()
time.sleep(1)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('text searched on google')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```

I hope someone can help me, and I hope you understand what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: This is very bad design. Instead, you should merge the scripts.

Comment: use imports? so import one script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't recommend merging the scripts, but if you strongly want 2 scripts, then you need to add a function into the second script and call it from the first. For example, this is what the first script needs to look like:

```python
import time
import second_script
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
second_script.main(driver)
```

Here, we import the script and call the function `main()` which we will define in the second script.

Now, this is what the second script should look like:

```python
import time

def main(driver):
    driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_box.send_keys('text searched on google')
    search_box.submit()
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.quit()
```

What we have done over here is create a function called `main()` and put all of the code into that function. We then added an argument called driver to avoid any errors and to merge the 2 drivers together.

Comment: @Score -6 really? from where. I don't remember sorry!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498874/python-how-to-bring-up-page-with-google-search-results/65498920#65498920

Comment: Ahhh yes I remember now!

Answer (score 0):

In your second script:

```
import time


def search(driver):
    driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_box.send_keys('text searched on google')
    search_box.submit()
    time.sleep(20)
    
    driver.quit()
```

In your first script:

```
import time
import second_script

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver87/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
second_script.search(driver)
```

This should work, fine however as others have said this is quite a bad design.