# Is there a way to make python open a webpage?

Tags: python, html

Im new to python and programming and wanted to make a simple program that opens a webpage after its execution, how can it be made?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217032/6328256

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: It's in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the most common way to do this is with [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) and a [webdriver manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/). If you don't need to open the whole webpage and just need the HTML, use [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) and [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean with *make python open a webpage*.
You can either call your default browser to open the URL with something like the following:

```
firefox.exe <url>
```

Or you can create an application using QT to show the webpage in "plain" Python: https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-webkit-browser/

If you need to interact with the page through your program, see the links in the answer mentioning selenium.

Comment: i meant the first thing, thanks a lot!